# Rails code segment explained

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

I am working on an app which has the below code:

```
def app
  @app ||= begin
    if !::File.exist? options[:config]
      abort "configuration #{options[:config]} not found"
    end

    app, myoptions = Rack::Builder.parse_file(self.options[:config], opt_parser)
    self.myoptions.merge! myoptions
    app
  end
end
```

I am struggling to get my head around several parts of it..

```
@app||= begin...end
```

Does this mean that if @app does not exist the block is run?

```
app ,options = rack::builder
```

What does the comma do to it?

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first assumptions was correct, it does say that if `@app` is nil, set it to whatever is returned in the block delimited with `begin, end`.

Regarding the comma, it works like this:

```
avar, bvar = "atest", "btest"
```

If you look at the source for `Rack:Builder.parse_file` then you will notice the last line

```
return app, options
```

So it is returning two values.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

@Craig-Taub ansewered the question,
I just want to add some notes:

Ruby commands are expressions which means they return value and you can assign them to variables.
You can read more about expressions and statements on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statement_%28computer_science%29#Expressions) and [PragProg](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_expressions.html).

Second is that when you return more than one value in a code block, Ruby will wrap it into a simple array and return it to the caller.
That's why it works like that.